# Detect mouse dblckick outside of nested element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

What I'm trying to do here is configure jQuery to have two boxes. The first box allows me to hide the first box and open a new one when clicked. The new (second) box is to be removed when clicking the body outside of the element.

I've been playing with different things including the exit/enter events, but can't seem to find a simple and straightforward way to get this effect.

I've set up a jsfiddle which demonstrates what I'm trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/wdAPu/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

to the event handler bound to `#opener`. This prevents the event from bubbling up and raising the event handler in the `#body`.

See the updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/wdAPu/3/

**Reference**: [`event.stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Now, this will still hide the new box if you double click *inside* the new box. To prevent this you have to bind an event handler to it and prevent the event from bubbling too. This can be done with the shortcut:

```
$('#content').dblclick(false);
```

(See here: http://jsfiddle.net/wdAPu/6/)

---

If you are creating the boxes dynamically, have a look at [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) and [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/).

Comment: This solves the first issue of events from both being triggered, but the second issue is where a dblclick inside #content will trigger the event tied to #body.

Comment: @user257493: Have you read the latest version of my answer? You have to add `$('#content').dblclick(false);`.